# Function in an if statement

Tags: php, kohana-3

I am trying to do an if statement if a function returns true and the else if it doesn't

Basically i need to show a html class in the return 1. I have try that below but I got an error.
`syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)`
This is what I have tried

```
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="stat" 
        <?php $access->getAccess() 
        if (getAccess == 1) {
        class="unpublished"
        }
        else {

    }
    ?>
    >
</div>
</div>
```

this is what the function looks like

```
 public function getAccess()
    {
        return $this->access;
    }
```

How can I do this right?

Comment: There are several issues with your syntax. Please check your use of brackets, semi-colon and $. Also, your logic doesnt make much sense. You might want to rethink whyt you are trying to do here and rewrite from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You PHP code isn't echoing anything, plus you are missing semicolons.

Try to simplify this a bit:

```
<div class="stat <?=$idea->getAccess() == 1 ? 'unpublished' : ''?>">
```

P.S. You need to put all your classes into the same attribute.

Comment: Thanks Rocket this works great. alot of the other answers were missing  `== 1` and this one got it just right

Comment: @SarahJames: Do you mean if you go to `test.com#3546`, that the page would scroll to this `<div>`?

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
<div class="stat <?php echo $idea->getAccess() ? 'unpublished' : ''; ?>"></div>
```

Comment: You forgot an `echo` ;)

Comment: @SarahJames What reason ?

Comment: If you look in the correct answer you are missing `== 1` because that was what I was trying to do in my fail if statement in my question. the function return 1 if its true and 0 if its a false.

Answer (score 1):

To call a function you need to use brackets:

```
$access = getAccess();//Not getAccess
```

I note that you call another getAccess function too so you may have meant to do:

```
$access = $idea->getAccess() ;
if ($access == 1) {
```

Edit: Others have pointed out you are also missing a `;`.

Comment: Best attempt of finding all of his problems so far. Still loads of them in his code though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to conceptually separate PHP from your HTML. What is happening is that your PHP is being interpreted by your web server resulting in a HTML document that will be delivered to the client. What you want is to add a class to the div if an $idea has access, something like this:

```
<div class="inner">
    <div class="stat <?php echo $idea->getAccess() ? "unpublished" : ""?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is equivalent to a much more complex (and in my opinion harder to read):

```
<div class="inner">
    <div class="stat <?php 
       if ($idea->getAccess()) {
         echo "unpublished";
       }
      ?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? check if the object you are using (in my answer that would be $idea) is an instance of the class that has the method "getAccess()", you can see the class of an object with a simple "echo get_class($idea);"

Comment: remember `class="unpublished"` is an HTML not php. `unpublished` is a css.

Comment: you cant have two class attributes (you can have more classes, but only 1 attribute) on a single element, you already have one class written on the html, "unpublished" will simply be added to your class if the condition is true, assuming that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a semi-colon:

```
getAccess();
```